# Insert header and footer on all webpages using javascript

Tags: javascript, header, footer

I have created index.html file and added header and footer sections. I want to show them on my other pages like about, contact but I don't want to copy them on all webpages. Please guide me how can I do it using vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another may be simpler way of writing JavaScript

```
const headerElement = document.querySelector("header");
const footerElement = document.querySelector("footer");

const fetchHeader = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("./header.txt");
    const template = await res.text();

    headerElement.innerHTML = template;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

const fetchFooter = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("./footer.txt");
    const template = await res.text();

    footerElement.innerHTML = template;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

fetchHeader();
fetchFooter();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom elements, by now it should be supported by major browsers:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./custom-elements.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-header></app-header>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
// custom-elements.js
class AppHeader extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
            <div style='border:2px solid red; padding:5px'>
                This is my header
            </div>
        `
    }
}
window.customElements.define('app-header', AppHeader)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

Comment: Yes, it works even if don't write inline css and link an external stylesheet. Linking it before other JS files with also work with other JS functionalities. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Global style will not be applied if shadow DOM is attached in the class constructor

Answer (score 1):

Copy your header and footer code to header.txt and footer.txt files and then just add this code to your JavaScript file.
Don't forget to:

- include JavaScript file to those pages where you want to show header
  and footer.
- check path for header and footer txt files.

You can also add header and footer code to separate JavaScript files as you like.

```
const fetchHeader = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("./header.txt");
    const template = await res.text();
    const parse = new DOMParser();
    const html = parse.parseFromString(template, "text/html");
    const header = html.querySelector("body header");

    document.body.prepend(header);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

const fetchFooter = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("./footer.txt");
    const template = await res.text();
    const parse = new DOMParser();
    const html = parse.parseFromString(template, "text/html");
    const footer = html.querySelector("body footer");

    document.body.append(footer);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

fetchHeader().then(fetchFooter);
```

If you want to add any kind of functionality like toggling menu on click, you can do this:

```
const getElements = () => {
  const nav = document.querySelector(".navbar");
  const menuBtn = document.querySelector("#menu-btn");

  menuBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("active");
  });

  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    nav.classList.remove("active");
  });
};
```

Now call this function after calling fetchHeader function because menu is in header

```
fetchHeader().then(getElements).then(fetchFooter);
// OR
fetchHeader().then(getElements);
fetchFooter();
```

Comment: Github respository: https://github.com/MuhammadIkram24/header-and-footer-js